# Content types complex relationships

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I'm trying to build a system where I have people, departments and facilities but they must link through a triple join table.

Basically, a person can belong to multiple departments OR can work multiple locations, but a department can be at multiple facilities (imagine a sub company with multiple locations at different buildings).

I'm wondering what is the best approach to build this in Drupal. Should I use a custom entity to tie these content types together?

I tried using Entity Reference but it doesn't seem to solve my problems as I was hoping for. I thought about creating another content type for Person-Location-Department but I was thinking on having these relationship get generated on the fly when creating a person.

[image: Entities schema]

Comment: You could try [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation). The relationships themselves are entities and can have fields attached

Comment: I just tried relations, and while it could work the UI doesn't seem to be very intuitive. Even after using [relation_select](https://drupal.org/project/relation_select)